# Setting validations for card expiry date in a checkout form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, checkout

Please be aware this checkout form will not actually be used to take payments

I need to apply validation restraints to prevent someone from setting their bank card expiry date before the current date but i am not sure how to do this.

```
<!--Option boxes-->
    <form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-50">
          <div class="input-control">
            <label for="expmonth">Expiry Month</label>
            <select id="expmonth" name="expmonth">
              <option value="01">January</option>
              <option value="02">February</option>
              <option value="03">March</option>
              <option value="04">April</option>
              <option value="05">May</option>
              <option value="06">June</option>
              <option value="07">July</option>
              <option value="08">August</option>
              <option value="09">September</option>
              <option value="10">October</option>
              <option value="11">November</option>
              <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-50">
            <!--Labels and Inputs-->
          <div class="input-control">  
            <label for="expyear">Exp Year</label>
            <select id="expyear" name="expyear">
              <option value="2022">2022</option>
              <option value="2023">2023</option>
              <option value="2024">2024</option>
              <option value="2025">2025</option>
              <option value="2026">2026</option>
              <option value="2027">2027</option>
              <option value="2028">2028</option>
              <option value="2029">2029</option>
              <option value="2030">2030</option>
              <option value="2031">2031</option>
              <option value="2032">2032</option>
              <option value="2033">2033</option>
              <option value="2034">2034</option>
              <option value="2035">2035</option>
              <option value="2036">2036</option>
              <option value="2037">2037</option>
              <option value="2038">2038</option>
              <option value="2039">2039</option>
              <option value="2040">2040</option>
              <option value="2041">2041</option>
              <option value="2042">2042</option>
              <option value="2043">2043</option>
              <option value="2044">2044</option>
              <option value="2045">2045</option>
              <option value="2046">2046</option>
              <option value="2047">2047</option>
              <option value="2048">2048</option>
              <option value="2049">2049</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <!--Labels and Inputs-->
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="sameadr"> Shipping address same as billing </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Checkout" class="btn">
  </form>
```

The code looks like this for my form  ^
What JS should i use?

The checkout form that i used is this one https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_checkout_form.asp

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use javascript to get the value of the selected date and then check if the selected date is behind the current date, if it is so then change the date to current date or you can write your own logic to handle this scenario.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. I would like a message to pop up under the boxes also saying "Please enter a valid expiry date" but i am a bit lost on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

as the HTML you use

you did apply some restrictions for the year

so the only thing you should put on your mind to

validate the month if the user entering the current year

like: 5 April 2022
this is not valid

so you can use this to validate the month
you can add some CSS to alert the user
I just disabled the button

```
    const d = new Date();
    const submitBtn = document.getElementById("btn");

const curruentMonth = d.getMonth() + 1; //the start is 0

function validate() {
  var selectYear = document.getElementById("expyear");
  var year = selectYear.options[selectYear.selectedIndex].value;
  var selectMonth = document.getElementById("expmonth");
  var month = selectMonth.options[selectMonth.selectedIndex].value;

  if (year == 2022) {
    if (month <= curruentMonth) {
      submitBtn.disabled = false;
    }
  }
  submitBtn.disabled = true;
}
validate();
```

---

your HTML

```
<form>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-50">
          <div class="input-control">
            <label for="expmonth">Expiry Month</label>
            <select id="expmonth" name="expmonth" onChange="validate()">
              <option value="1">January</option>
              <option value="2">February</option>
              <option value="3">March</option>
              <option value="4">April</option>
              <option value="5">May</option>
              <option value="6">June</option>
              <option value="7">July</option>
              <option value="8">August</option>
              <option value="9">September</option>
              <option value="10">October</option>
              <option value="11">November</option>
              <option value="12">December</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-50">
            <!--Labels and Inputs-->
          <div class="input-control">  
            <label for="expyear">Exp Year</label onChange="validate()">
            <select id="expyear" name="expyear">
              <option value="2022">2022</option>
              <option value="2023">2023</option>
              <option value="2024">2024</option>
              <option value="2025">2025</option>
              <option value="2026">2026</option>
              <option value="2027">2027</option>
              <option value="2028">2028</option>
              <option value="2029">2029</option>
              <option value="2030">2030</option>
              <option value="2031">2031</option>
              <option value="2032">2032</option>
              <option value="2033">2033</option>
              <option value="2034">2034</option>
              <option value="2035">2035</option>
              <option value="2036">2036</option>
              <option value="2037">2037</option>
              <option value="2038">2038</option>
              <option value="2039">2039</option>
              <option value="2040">2040</option>
              <option value="2041">2041</option>
              <option value="2042">2042</option>
              <option value="2043">2043</option>
              <option value="2044">2044</option>
              <option value="2045">2045</option>
              <option value="2046">2046</option>
              <option value="2047">2047</option>
              <option value="2048">2048</option>
              <option value="2049">2049</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    <!--Labels and Inputs-->
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="sameadr"> Shipping address same as billing </label>
      <input id="btn" type="submit" value="Checkout" class="btn">
  </form>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you KroKing. This is exactlythe kind of reply i am looking for but the code you entered when i put it into my code but unfortunately it has not worked. If i put it into my current code then nothing happens but if i put the code you have provided me into its own file then the button does become disabled but even when the input is as it should be it still remains disabled

Perhaps i am supposed to do something here but my lack of experience is limiting me here

Comment: your welcome man,

you should search about how to add action listener to the Combobox using js

I missed this, sorry

Comment: Ah im really struggling with this too. I know what the event listener is supposed to do and im trying to follow this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Its just not doing anything 
I tried using this as my listener but it does not do anything document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", validate);

Comment: I will make it for u rn

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Is there a way i can send you the full code of my web page. I have a bunch of other validation constraints that i have done succesfully while following online tutorials and i want it to resemble this. By adding an ID to the submit button it actually stops the other validation constraints from working.

Comment: https://codepen.io/GuardianLiam/pen/wvyqPYm

I uploaded the full code to here so that you can see what i have done
Minus the code that you have given me

Comment: you can upload it to GitHub repo and we collaborate

Comment: I see what you did you can add 

required
in every required input tag 

that will help you for prevent user from submitting empty data

Comment: Okay, i have uploaded to github. I need to add you as a collaborator. Adding required actually stops the validations i have added from working.

Comment: mahmoudgalalz
in github add me there or give me your repo